# Google Feed API: more than one feed

Tags: javascript, google-feed-api

Question for those that have used the [Google Feed API](https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/). I've got the thing working just fine -

```
google.load('feeds', '1', init);

function init() {
  f1 = new google.feeds.Feed(feedUrl1);
  f2 = new google.feeds.Feed(feedUrl2);
  f1.load(function(result) {
    // render my 1st feed
  });
  f2.load(function(result) {
    // render my 2nd feed
  });
}
```

How do I make this work without the `feedControl`? That one has only one method, `draw()`, and I need to customize my markup which I don't believe you can do with `draw()`.

It looks like only one instance of `google.feeds.Feed()` can be done on one page, so the code above will not work in the sense that it will only pull the last feed, `f2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, there is no real way to do this with the Google feed API.